# Jmeter TCP Connection

Tags: http, tcp, jmeter

Below is the configured thread group

[image]

```
Thread Group
 |
 |--> HTTP SAMPLE
```

I am opening 5 threads in 5 seconds with loop count is 5. It means in each thread 5 HHTP request will be sent, so total 25 request.

Thread 1 : TCP CONNECTION OPENED --> HTTP REQUEST SENT ---> HTTP RESPONSE RECEIVED.

Question: After receiving response whether TCP connection will be closed and again TCP connection will be opened and then HTTP request will be sent?

Or once response is received in same TCP connection next HTTP request will be sent?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do you set in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, if you tick  `Use KeepAlive` box - then JMeter will send [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header with the value of `keep-alive`

[image]

[image]

it means that the underlying TCP connection will remain open and the next HTTP Request sampler(s) will be reusing this connection.

If you untick the box JMeter will send `Connection` header with the value of `close` and next HTTP Request sampler will re-establish the connection.

You need to check what's going on in reality using your browser developer tools or an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [configure JMeter to behave exactly like the real browser does](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)